# java externals jars not included when using maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, external

folks,

I am new to Java. I have seen including external jars and compile that. External jars usually contains lot of class files. So when I include these external jars in my project and if I create a new JAR, I can see these external jars included as part of my JAR file.

But I have seen cases in which these external jars are not included as part of my JAR file when using **Maven** ? Why is it like that ? (Example, when you write hadoop map reduce programs in java, you are referring lot of external jars but none of these external jars are included in the final jar I create from my project.)

thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the external libraries packaged in the jar, you need to use a tool like OneJar. There is a Maven plugin for OneJar at https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/.

Comment: So the external jars are not necessary to execute my jar in a customer PC ? That is no need to package these external jars into my RAR for it to execute in a diffrent pc ?

Comment: The external JARs will need to be present in the classpath when you run the program, otherwise you will get UnsatisfiedLinkExceptions at runtime. OneJar will make sure all the external JARs are present in one big Jar that you can give to your customers.

Comment: But when I create a runnable jar in case of of developing map reduce programs, I am including lot of external jars from apache  in this project. But when I create runnable jars , none of the apache hadoop jars are included when I extract. But when I run this program in the cluster it is working fine ? So from where this is getting the external JARS?